# When editing participants, can I avoid having all questions from all current events displayed?

Tags: civievent, 4.4

My site frequently has multiple CiviEvent-based registrations running. It is common for some questions to overlap (First Name, Last Name, Company) and for some questions to be unique to each registration (Do you want to attend session X?). As well, some of the unique questions require an answer.

When I go to edit a participant's details via "Find Participant" or "Advanced Search" I am presented with all of the currently enabled fields for all of the current registrations and the system compels me to answer all of the required fields from all of them.

Some of my events use Profiles that contain custom fields from more than one record type (Contact, Individual, Participant). This seems to be an impediment to using that Profile as an option when using the "Batch Update Participants Via Profile" action.

Is there a way for me to view and edit just the questions/responses in the fields related to one of my events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to limit the custom participant data to a specific event or event type and then it shouldn't show up in the back end for events you didn't mean it to.

This is done on the custom data itself (under "used for") rather than in the profile. Also to note, you usually only want to 'require' data inside the profile not inside the custom data set.

Comment: I think Ray's last comment is the crux. Do not make the Custom Field 'required' - but make it 'required' only in the Profile

Comment: Thank you, RayWright! Your last suggestion did the trick. My over-zealous application of the Required state was my own undoing.